# Utility and Pipeline Data Model 2016 Valves Layer

Tags: utility-network, arcgis-data-model

In the UPDM2016 data model we have a single Valve layer.

Do I need to store both inline valves for mainlines and curb valves for services in the Valve layer together or is there another layer?

[UPDM 2016 Edition](https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-10493-updm2016updatezip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i can't actually speak from personal experience with the UPDM model, but from a logical perspective, at a high level, a valve is a valve, irrespective of the network of the pipe it exists on.

This of course is not entirely true! In a GIS and on the assumption its a Water network, a valve may be functioning as:

- A shutoff/isolation valve (design to stop the flow of water)
- Pressure reduction valve (Design to reduce the pressure of the water going through it)
- Check valve (which are also known as backflow prevention device, or flow control valve, which prevent water from flowing back up the network).
  (similar ideas exist with Gas network also
  ).
  An Isolation Valve, on a mainline or service line, would be stored in the same table in the database, with additional attributes/join fields attributing their functional and material differences, as well as perhaps the network it is part of.

A Pressure Reduction Valve however, should not be stored on the same table as an isolation valve, as it performs different function, particularly with regards to isolation traces, direction modelling and integration with Hydraulic modelling software.

Same with a Check Valve.

The above problems may simply be solved through nomencalture.
the 'Valve'table only stores isolation (or similar) valves.
Pressure Reduction valves should be called 'Pressure Reduction Device'
Check Valves called 'Backflow Prevention Device'.... or similar.
Solve your modelling problems through a simple change in naming convention!